# Compare Two Select Lists, and Require User to Select Different Values

Tags: entities

Use case:  I'm presenting the User with two Select Lists populated with the same People names.

The first select list is Primary Person, the second select list is Backup Person.

The User must select a different value from each list. The same Person can't be a primary and backup. If the User attempts to save the page using the same value, Drupal will throw an error.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

For the [Drupal form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#properties), this would be handled with your validation handler. Have it check your 2 form values for equality, and throw an error if so.

```
function MYFORMBUILDER_validate($form, $form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['person_primary'] == $form_state['values']['person_backup']) {
    form_set_error('person_primary', t('The primary and backup person must be different'));
    form_set_error('person_backup', t('The primary and backup person must be different'));
    array_pop($_SESSION['messages']['error']); //Remove duplicate message
  }
}
```

Comment: He may also need hook_form_alter() to add his custom validate handler to the existing node form first in the right order.

Comment: Yeah, this answer assumes a custom form. If it's created by another module you'll need `hook_form_alter()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Should I put this in a Block with PHP filter, or in a custom module?

Comment: Custom module. A validation handler would not work embedded in a PHP filter block.

Comment: Ok. So If I understand all of comments - I will be creating a custom module, using hook_form_alter, and the above function ?

Comment: Correct, if this is a pre-existing form (not a custom one that already exists in your own module), then you'll need a `hook_form_alter()` invocation.